# How can I make the Array List be called in another class java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, return

I need to write a code that checks all the words in an array list and tells me how many of these have a certain length. I understand how to do that, but I can't figure out how to make the `ArrayList` to be read in the second class so I can apply it in the program.

**MAIN**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    java.util.ArrayList myList = new java.util.ArrayList();
    myList.add("cat");
    myList.add("mouse");
    myList.add("frog");
    myList.add("dog");
    myList.add("dog");
    int len = in.nextInt();
    WordList wl = new WordList();
    wl.numWordsOfLength(len);
  }
}
```

**SECOND CLASS**

```
public class WordList{
  public int numWordsOfLength(int len){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){

      if(((String)myList.get(i)).length()==len){
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the list as parameter:

```
  public int numWordsOfLength(int len, List<String> myList){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<myList.size;i++){

      if((myList.get(i)).length()==len){
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```

or via the `WordList` Constructor:

```
import java.util.List;
public class WordList{

    private final List<String> myList;
    WordList(List<String> myList){
        this.myList = myList;
    }
    public int numWordsOfLength(int len){
        int count = 0;
        for (String s : myList) {
            if (s.length() == len) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Side node instead of :

```
    java.util.ArrayList myList = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

just do :

```
   import java.util.List;
   ....
   List<String> myList = new ArrayList();
```

Full Running example:

```
public class Test {

    public static class WordList{

        private final List<String> myList;
        WordList(List<String> myList){
            this.myList = myList;
        }
        public int numWordsOfLength(int len){
            int count = 0;
            for (String s : myList) {
                if (s.length() == len) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
    }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
            myList.add("cat");
            myList.add("mouse");
            myList.add("frog");
            myList.add("dog");
            myList.add("dog");
            int len = in.nextInt();
            WordList wl = new WordList(myList);
            System.out.println(wl.numWordsOfLength(len));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your interpretation of "read in the second class".

My guess is you want the second class to have "myList" as a private variable, so the code will work when you call the numWordsOfLength() function.

In order to do this, you should pass the array you built to WordList as a dependency. There are generally two ways to give an object a dependency. Either when you create the object (constructor based) or later by calling a method (setters).

So in main, your goal would be to do either:

```
WordList wl = new WordList();
wl.setList(myList)
wl.numWordsOfLength(len);
```

Or:

```
WordList wl = new WordList(myList);
wl.numWordsOfLength(len);
```

Either way, you will have to add "myList" variable inside the WordList and then expose it either via a separate setter method (setList) or in the constructor itself.

I'd prefer a constructor in this case, since the name of the class "WordList" implies that it *IS* a list of things and therefore should encapsulate the thing it is.

i.e.

```
public class WordList{

  private List<String> myList;

  public WordList(List<String> listOfWords) {
    this.myList = listOfWords;
  }
  
  public int numWordsOfLength....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that second class at all, if you use Java 8+:

```
    ...
    java.util.ArrayList<String> myList = new java.util.ArrayList();
    myList.add("cat");
    myList.add("mouse");
    myList.add("frog");
    myList.add("dog");
    myList.add("dog");
    int len = in.nextInt();
    int count = myList.stream().map(String::length).filter(c->c==len).count(); <--that's your answer
    ...
```

If you prefer to use that second class, you can just use this "count" expression in your `numWordsOfLength` method in the `WordList` class once you've passed the list there as the previous answers suggest.

BTW, the loop in your WordList class seem to be incorrect: you're only iterating the list up to `len`, instead you want to iterate over the entire list. I assume the `len` variable is the searched lengths of a word:

```
 public int numWordsOfLength(int len, List<String> list){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
      if(list.get(i).length()==len){
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```